# Sum a column in pandas DataFrame based on other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have several columns in a pandas DataFrame ('SEC', 'DeviceName', 'DAY', and 'SPRAY').  I need to sum 'SEC' by 'DeviceName' for each day in the 'DAY' column, where 'SPRAY' == 1.

For example:

```
DeviceName       SEC     DAY     SPRAY
Applied_AA-6     1800    4       1
Applied_AA-6     600     4       0
Applied_AA-6     1373    5       1
Applied_AA-15    10      4       0
Applied_AA-15    1800    5       1
Applied_AA-15    13      5       1
```

The results should be:

```
                 Day 4   Day 5
Applied_AA-6     1800    1373
Applied_AA-15    0       1813
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another possible solution, which is based on [`pandas.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html):

```
(df[df['SPRAY'].eq(1)]
 .pivot_table(
     index='DeviceName', columns='DAY', values='SEC', 
     aggfunc='sum', sort=False, fill_value=0)
 .rename_axis(None, axis=1).reset_index())
```

Output:

```
      DeviceName     4     5
0   Applied_AA-6  1800  1373
1  Applied_AA-15     0  1813
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html)

```
df[df['SPRAY'].eq(1)].groupby(['DeviceName', 'DAY'])['SEC'] \
                     .sum() \
                     .unstack() \
                     .fillna(0)
```

---

```
DAY                 4       5
             
Applied_AA-15       0  1813.0
Applied_AA-6   1800.0  1373.0
```